# Angularjs href show "please fill out this field" if required fields are not filled

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, href

I want to have input validation so that if the user clicks on href, they should see "please fill out this field" if the required input texts are not filled. It works if I change a href to button, but that is not what I am looking for.

Here is what I am trying to do:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pd7ty1ak/2/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myform">
        <input type="text" ng-model='name' ng-required="true" />
        <a href ng-click="myform.$valid && dostuff()">Preview</a>
    </form>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name=undefined;
    $scope.dostuff = function(){
        //do stuff
    };
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use either class or state to do what you need

Input fields have the following states:

- `$untouched` The field has not been touched yet
- `$touched` The field has been touched
- `$pristine` The field has not been modified yet
- `$dirty The` field has been modified
- `$invalid` The field content is not valid
- `$valid` The field content is valid

They are all properties of the input field, and are either true or false.

Forms have the following states:

- `$pristine` No fields have been modified yet
- `$dirty` One or more have been modified
- `$invalid` The form content is not valid
- `$valid` The form content is valid
- `$submitted` The form is submitted

The following classes are added to, or removed from, input fields:

- `ng-untouched` The field has not been touched yet
- `ng-touched` The field has been touched
- `ng-pristine` The field has not been  modified yet
- `ng-dirty` The field has been modified
- `ng-valid` The field content is valid
- `ng-invalid` The field content is not valid
- `ng-valid-key` One key for each validation. Example: `ng-valid-required`, useful when there are more than one thing that must be validated
- `ng-invalid-key` Example: `ng-invalid-required`

The following classes are added to, or removed from, forms:

- `ng-pristine` No fields has not been modified yet
- `ng-dirty` One or more fields has been modified
- `ng-valid` The form content is valid
- `ng-invalid` The form content is not valid
- `ng-valid-key` One key for each validation. Example: `ng-valid-required`, useful when there are more than one thing that must be validated
- `ng-invalid-key` Example: `ng-invalid-required`

The classes are removed if the value they represent is `false`.

Maybe this could help you:

```
<input name="myName" ng-model="myName" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.myName.$touched && myForm.myName.$invalid">please fill out this field</span>
```

Or you could use css to show the message.

Hope this helps. Good luck!